# Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version xxxxxxxx. The Zend Engine API version 2xxxxxxxx which is installed, is newer. XAMPP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug, linux-mint

I'm working to figure out how to debug PHP in VSCode with Xdebug, running Linux Mint Vera (Victoria).

Followed steps outlined in the Xdebug installation wizard (here: https://xdebug.org/wizard) after copying the `phpinfo();` verified:

```text
Installation Wizard
Summary

    Xdebug installed: 3.2.2
    Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
    Windows: no
    Zend Server: no
    PHP Version: 8.2.4
    Zend API nr: 420220829
    PHP API nr: 20220829
    Debug Build: no
    Thread Safe Build: no
    OPcache Loaded: no
    Configuration File Path: /opt/lampp/etc
    Configuration File: /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
    Extensions directory: /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829

You're already running the latest Xdebug version
```

Configured VSCode to point to `/opt/lampp/bin/php`

... began debugging a php file and got this message in VSCode's debug console:

```text
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 420210902.
The Zend Engine API version 420220829 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Derick Rethans at https://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of Xdebug.
```

... followed the steps outlined there above; using correct `phpize`: in `/opt/lampp/bin`

[image]

and verified the numbers Do match:

[image]

... ultimately I'm lost; not sure which configuration file/setting I'm missing in this 7th round of a many month boxing match between myself and Xdebug (tag teaming w/xampp, linux).

Apologize poor post quality; long time viewer first time asking.

Comment: ... for what it's worth, I know it's not the right way, but after posting this I located the original xdebug.so buried in folder: /usr/lib/php/20210902 ... I understand there's probably a config file somewhere; for now/for testing I copied the new xdebug.so binary that ws created from all the correct xampp headers and replaced the old version with the new one; but the config somewhere pointing at the old directory

It seems to work; just get a warning now that says: ```Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded```

Comment: You have multiple PHP versions on your system, and when you debug (on the CLI, perhaps) through VS Code, it uses the other `php` version.